# Exporting location data into csv in flutter

Tags: flutter, csv, dart

I'm trying to export location data into a csv file.
I tried using the flutter documentations but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

the app is running ok, I can see the location data on screen,
so I think the problem is with
writing the data into the csv file.
Another thing that I noticed is that my app doesn't have a folder inside
android/data.

Am I asking for permission in the wrong way?
I added the following line to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Just for being clear, the problem is that the file isn't created.
I'll be happy for some help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:different/widgets/StatGridDrive.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';


class DataStorage {
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    Permission.storage.request();
    final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/locationData.csv');
  }

  Future<File> writeData(String data) async {
    final file = await _localFile;

    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString(data);
  }
}

class DriveScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final DataStorage data;
  DriveScreen({Key key, @required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DriveScreenState createState() => _DriveScreenState();
}

class _DriveScreenState extends State<DriveScreen> {
  @override
  final Location location = Location();

  LocationData _location;
  StreamSubscription<LocationData> _locationSubscription;
  String _error;

  Future<void> _listenLocation() async {
    _locationSubscription =
        location.onLocationChanged.handleError((dynamic err) {
          setState(() {
            _error = err.code;
          });
          _locationSubscription.cancel();
        }).listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
          setState(() {
            _error = null;
            _location = currentLocation;
          });
        });
  }

  Future<void> _stopListen() async {
    _locationSubscription.cancel();
  }

  Future<File> newData() {
    // Write the variable as a string to the file.
    return widget.data.writeData(_location.longitude.toString() + "," + _location.latitude.toString());
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.baby_changing_station,
            ),
          ),
          title: Text('LyftOff'),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF282828)),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF333333),
      body: SizedBox(
        height: 325,
        child: StatsGrid(
            distance: 15, speed: 100, time: (_error ?? '${_location ?? "0"}')),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
        height: 60.0,
        width: 185.0,
        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            _listenLocation();
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          label: Text(
            'התחל נסיעה',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
            ),
          ),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.car_rental,
            size: 30.0,
          ),
          splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the problems.
and I want to share some insights from the process.

### insights:

1.There’s no need to ask permissions if you don’t need the user will have access to the data.
so I Swapped `getExternalStorageDirectory()` with `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`;

2.when you use `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` the data will be in
`root/data/data/"app name"`.

3.when you write into file, if you want to append new data, you need to pass
`mode:FileMode.append` as an argument, otherwise you'll just write over the old line.
something Like this:
`file.writeAsString(data, mode:FileMode.append);`

### main reason why the code didn't work:

1. I didn't initialize the Data storage class, when I called the current page from main.
   main code:

```
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new DriveScreen(data: DataStorage())),
            );
          },
```

you need to call `data: "your_class_name"`

2. I didn't called the write function `newData()`.
   It was added here:

```
  Future<void> _listenLocation() async {
    _locationSubscription =
        location.onLocationChanged.handleError((dynamic err) {
          setState(() {
            _error = err.code;
          });
          _locationSubscription.cancel();
        }).listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
          setState(() {
            _error = null;
            _location = currentLocation;
          });
          newData();
        });
  }
```

### The working code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:different/widgets/StatGridDrive.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';



class DataStorage {
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/locationData.csv');
  }

  Future<File> writeData(String data) async {
    final file = await _localFile;

    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString(data, mode:FileMode.append);
  }
}

class DriveScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final DataStorage data;
  DriveScreen({Key key, @required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DriveScreenState createState() => _DriveScreenState();
}

class _DriveScreenState extends State<DriveScreen> {

  final Location location = Location();

  LocationData _location;
  StreamSubscription<LocationData> _locationSubscription;
  String _error;

  Future<void> _listenLocation() async {
    _locationSubscription =
        location.onLocationChanged.handleError((dynamic err) {
          setState(() {
            _error = err.code;
          });
          _locationSubscription.cancel();
        }).listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
          setState(() {
            _error = null;
            _location = currentLocation;
          });
          newData();
        });
  }
  Future<void> _stopListen() async {
    _locationSubscription.cancel();
  }

  Future<File> newData() {
    // Write the variable as a string to the file.
    return widget.data.writeData('${_location.longitude.toString() + "," + _location.latitude.toString()} \n');
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              _stopListen();
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.baby_changing_station,
            ),
          ),
          title: Text('LyftOff'),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF282828)),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF333333),
      body: SizedBox(
        height: 325,
        child: StatsGrid(
            distance: 15, speed: 100, time: (_error ?? '${_location ?? "0"}')),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
        height: 60.0,
        width: 185.0,
        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            _listenLocation();
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          label: Text(
            'התחל נסיעה',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
            ),
          ),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.car_rental,
            size: 30.0,
          ),
          splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```